# How to print json data within array element as string

Tags: php, json, foreach

**I have an Array** 
Array 
( [0] => ["1","2","7","8","9"] )

**and i want to like that**

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 [4] => 9 )

**i try foreach loop**

```
foreach($no_a as $key=>$val){ 

    foreach($val as $k=>$v){ 

        $newp_arr[] $v ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, you are missing an `=` when you are assigning your `$v` variable.

Comment: i add = but not working @Nicolas

Comment: If you just want to remove 1 level of array `$result = $source[0];`

Comment: Where's the json data? Is `["1","2","7","8","9"]` a string containing a serialized json array or is it a real PHP array?

Comment: $df['ss_fl'] = ["1","2","7","8","9"]; is a Serializedjson data in table @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Try something like: `$foo = json_decode($df['ss_fl'], true);`. Now `$foo` should contain a proper PHP array.

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $no_a[0];
$new_result = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 21 ; $i++) { 
    # code...
    $num = $result[$i];
    if(is_numeric($num))
    {
        $new_result[] = $result[$i];
    }

}

print_r($new_result);
```

Comment: I achieve this by following way @Nigel Ren

Comment: Please add additional description as to how and why this solution works